# How to display children components in an Anchor tag in DraftJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

**Updated post with a working example in CodeSandbox**

We're using DraftJS to insert an `<a>` around some selected text in an editor.

### Original state

It presently works by wrapping the anchor tag around the highlighted text.

E.g., for this text: 
  `Foo bar foo`.
If the user highlights "bar", our editor will render `<a href='http://...'>bar</a>`

The current code to alter the content state:

```
this.applyLink = () => {
  const { editorState } = this.state;
  const selectionState = editorState.getSelection();

  const entity = Entity.create("LINK", "MUTABLE", {
    url: "http://foo.com"
  });

  const update = RichUtils.toggleLink(editorState, selectionState, entity);

  this.onChange(update);
};
```

The actual Link that is getting rendered:

```
const Link = props => {
  const { url } = props.contentState.getEntity(props.entityKey).getData();
  return (
    <a href={url} style={styles.link}>
      {props.children}
    </a>
  );
};
```

The custom decorator which creates the Link:

```
function findLinkEntities(contentBlock: ContentBlock, callback, contentState) {
  contentBlock.findEntityRanges(character => {
    const entityKey = character.getEntity();

    return (
      entityKey !== null &&
      contentState.getEntity(entityKey).getType() === "LINK"
    );
  }, callback);
}
```

### Desired state

Our product owner has asked that the links retain any other elements which may be selected.

E.g., for text with a custom entity: 
  `Foo bar <custom-entity .../> foo`.

If the user highlights "bar" *and* the custom entity, we want to render the anchor tag around both of them.  I.e. `<a href='http://...'>bar <custom-entity .../> </a>`.

However, our code is stripping anything that isn't text-- the `<custom-entity>` disappears.

### Update with CodeSandbox

I've created an example which reproduces this in CodeSandbox, [available here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-resonance-06xf1)

The CodeSandbox page detail the steps to reproduce.  In short if you add text and the Custom Entity (using the button), then highlight the content like so:
[image: Before clicking 'apply link']

Then with that highlight still active, click 'Apply link', the editor renders:

[image: custom entity disappears]

^ Note the Custom Entity disappeared after the Link was applied.

Can anyone help figure out how to keep that Custom Entity inside the anchor tag?

Comment: No love?  Still trying to figure this out

Comment: Can you post a stackblitz/codesandbox demo of the code?

Comment: @MunimMunna I added a codesandbox example.  Thanks for the recommendation.  Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: From documentation,_ An entity is an object that represents metadata for a range of **text**_, so the tags are cleaned to give a text to Entity.  Maybe this [plug-in](https://www.draft-js-plugins.com/plugin/anchor) can inspire you

Answer (score 1):

`Draft.js` does not support [nested entities](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/issues/246), but there are some options to [nest decorators](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/issues/542) if you can use them instead.

In particular, take a look as this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/paulyoung85/2unzgt68/).